# MudTooltip doesn't always disappear when cursor moves away

Tags: javascript, css, tooltip, mudblazor

I am using MudTooltip in a Blazor web app (.NET 8, MudBlazor 6.18.0, Chrome).

When I hover over the menu icon, the tooltip appears.

Right-click the same menu icon and open it in a new tab.

Go back to the original tab and the tooltip is still there, even when not hovering over it.
Sometimes, I got the same bug with left-click.

Is this a bug of MudBlazor/MudTooltip? Any way to fix it permanently/temporarily?

[image]

Comment: I guess it happens because the item gets the focus and keeps it until something else is clicked/focused. Can you try setting ShowOnFocus="false" on the tooltip?

Comment: @Uerschel Nice solution. It worked. Thanks a lot. You can give it an answer so I can mark it as an official solution. Besides, an upvote would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the MenuItem / Button gets the focus and doesn't lose it.

You can set the Property `ShowOnFocus` to `false`.